# What are tickets used for?

Tags: rollercoaster-tycoon-4

Tickets are, apparently, the premium currency in [RCT4](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/rollercoaster-tycoon-4-mobile/id797639732?mt=8).  What are these tickets used for?  Can you still fully play the game without purchasing any?

Comment: Tickets *and coins* are the premium currency. It's a full-on free-to-play model on a pay-to-play game. I'm going to go ahead and cut my rant short right there.

Comment: @Unionhawk Yea, I tried to remove all the ranting from the question before posting.  Anyway, I did not know that coins are also a premium currency.  The screenshots on the app store don't seem to suggest that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tickets, as you mention, are a premium currency in Roller Coaster Tycoon 4. They can be used to rush the construction of attractions as well as building more elaborate roller coasters.

[image]

In addition to purchasing tickets via microtransactions, each new park starts off with a number of tickets and you can earn additional tickets by completing quests and inviting friends. You don't *have* to spend real life money to play the game.